# Azure Data Factory Mapping Dataflow add Rownumber

Tags: azure-data-factory, row-number

I thought this would be fairly straight forward but i can't really find a simple way of doing it.  I want to add a unique rownumber to a source dataset in a ADF Mapping Dataflow. In SSIS i would have done this with a script component but there's no option for that as far as i can see in ADF.  I've looked for suitable functions in the derived columns expressions editor and also the aggregate component but there doesn't appear to be one.

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Many options:

1. Add a surrogate key transform
2. Hash row columns in Derived Column using SHA2
3. Use the rowNumber() function in a Window transformation

Give those a shot and let us know what you think

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:

1. Add a Column with the same value to all the rows (I've used an integer with value = 1);
2. Added a window, using the column create previously on step 1 (Over);
3. Add a column on step 4 to window (window columns) with any name and `rowNumber()` as expression;